# React/Next - reference a function within useContext

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I moved the firebase auth to a useContext components.
The only thing i am trying to figure out is how to reference the async GoogleLogin function from the useContext to the button (onClick event) on the Login page.

**That's my UserContext file**

```
import { signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../utils/firebase';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const UserContext = createContext(null);

export const UserProvider = ({ children}) => {
  const route = useRouter();
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

  const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const GoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
export default UserContext;
```

**That's my Login component**

```
import UserContext from '../../components/UserContext';
import {useContext } from 'react';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';

const Login = () => {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div className='shadow-xl mt-32 p-10 text-gray-700'>
      <h2 className='text-2xl font-medium'>Join Today</h2>
      <div className='py-4'>
        <h3 className='py-4'>Sign in with one of the providers</h3>
        <button
          onClick={GoogleLogin}
          className='text-white bg-gray-700 w-full font-medium rounded-lg flex align-middle p-4 gap-2'>
          <FcGoogle className='text-2xl'></FcGoogle> Sign in with Google
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `UserContext.Provider value` to an object like

**UserContext file**

```js
// other code
<UserContext.Provider value={{user, GoogleLogin}}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
// rest of the code
```

**Login component**

```js
// other code
const {user, GoogleLogin} = useContext(UserContext);

// rest of your code
```

read more in new beta react documentation [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext)

Comment: That's what i actually tried but the function is being executed even though its in a callback function!?1?

Comment: As soon as i add the "GoogleLogin" to the Provider value the function is being executed. Any other idea?

Comment: put `console.log` inside GoogleLogin body function, normally function will not be called before adding () / to execute the function

Comment: Why do you think the console.log would help? Or do you want to see the log?

Comment: The problem was that i was assigning the user wrong! If you look at the Login component the user should be in an object e.g. {user}.